# Prove: $C(B)\cap N(A)=\{0\}\rightarrow Rank(B)\leq Rank(A) $

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A,B\in \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ s.t $C(B)\cap N(a)=\{0\}$
>
> Prove: $Rank(B)\leq Rank(A)$

Saying $C(B)\cap N(a)=\{0\}$ means that if we look at the space of $\mathbb{F}^{n}$ the linear span of the columns of $B$ and the linear span of all the vectors that are not in the linear span of the columns have no shared vectors (else from the trivial one $\{0\}$).

The columns of $B$ spans at most $\mathbb{F}^{n}$ and so does the Null space of $A$ so if there is no intersection between the both there are 3 options: a. $B$ spans the whole $\mathbb{F}^{n}$ space and the null space of $A$ has just the $0$ vector, b. the opposite, c. the dimension of the $C(B)$ and $C(a)$ sum up to $n$

I did not manage to address the issue fromally, how should I approach it? I have $Dim(U+V)=Dim(U)+Dim(V)-Dim(U\cap V)$ and the rank-nullity theorem at my disposal

Second try:

$Dim(C(B)\cap N(A))=0$

$Dim(C(B)+ N(A))=Dim(C(B))+Dim(N(A))$

$Dim(C(B)+ N(A))=Rank(B)+n-Rank(A)$

$Rank(A)=n+Rank(B)-Dim(C(B)+ N(A))$

Can we say something on $Dim(C(B)+ N(A))?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can say it's $\leq n$, because it's the dimension of a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^n$

Then, continuing from where you left off, $$Rank(B) = Rank(A) - n + Dim(C(B)+N(A)) \leq Rank(A) - n + n = Rank(A)$$

Comment: So it does not help to prove the claim

Comment: @gbox It does help. I edited my answer to clarify how.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, here's a construction.

Let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_s\}$ be a basis for $C(B)$ and consider $\{Av_1,\ldots,Av_n\}$.  If
$$\sum_{k=1}^s \lambda_kAv_k=0$$
then $\sum\lambda_kv_k$ is in $C(B)$ and in $N(A)$, so it is the zero vector.  Hence all the $\lambda_k$ are $0$.  This shows that the $Av_k$ are linearly independent.

Hence $C(A)$ contains $s$ independent vectors, so its dimension is ${}\ge s$.  That is, $rank(A)\ge rank(B)$.